# NumberFormatException SOLR for String field

Tags: solr, solrcloud, numberformatexception

New to SOLR, trying to stream a large document onto my SolrCloud instance. I am not picky about types at the moment, so everything is a string.

Field in question: (taken from schema.xml)

```
  <field name="student_count" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Trying to insert:

```
2.5
```

Error:

```
"java.lang.NumberFormatException":
Error adding field 'student_count'='2.5' msg=For input string: \"2.5\"
```

I'm wondering why the updates are not working, is it not picking up my schema? Why is SOLR trying to convert a string to a number when the predefined schema is already a string?

Comment: Then that's not your schema - you might be running in schemaless mode and the first value indexed for the field was a regular integer.

Comment: Does schemaless mode need to be explicitly turned on? When I created a new collection with my schema.xml, I am able to see the fields under the "schema" tab on the UI. How come it isn't using that to insert when I try to update?